# storing clicks to a database table?

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

How do i make the following script store the clicks to a database? i found this code but when i refresh the browser it doesnt store the count.

```
(function($) {
$('.btn-counter').on('click', function(event, count) {
event.preventDefault();

var $this = $(this),
    count = $this.attr('data-count'),
    active = $this.hasClass('active'),
    multiple = $this.hasClass('multiple-count');

// First method, allows to add custom function
// Use when you want to do an ajax request
/* if (multiple) {
    $this.attr('data-count', ++count);
    // Your code here
} else {
    $this.attr('data-count', active ? --count : ++count).toggleClass('active');
    // Your code here
} */

// Second method, use when ... I dunno when but it looks cool and that's why it is here
$.fn.noop = $.noop;
$this.attr('data-count',
    ! active || multiple ? ++count : --count
)[multiple ? 'noop' : 'toggleClass']('active');

})
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

... it wouldn't have the functionality you want, because you are storing the count/data in your DOM object, which is refreshing and defaults to initial state once you are refreshing whole webpage. It cant be used as a 'database' as you called. You can use `document.cookie` instead, which will store information for you. But, it would be cleaned whenever your browser history and cookies are removed: either invoked by user or by browser itself. 
You need server-side script(s) in whatever language (PHP, ASP etc.) that interacts with a database you hold, and updates/inserts data to that db.

Comment: Thanks, so what would the code be that i need for either one of those methods?

This is my website i am using it one http://dreamsynk.com/

Its a website like button. So preferably i would like it to be stored to a db.

Comment: I found this but i have no clue how to implement it http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/256691-jquery-click-counter/